# Chrome extension redirect to URL using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a extension that redirects any given URL from a form to it's result that comes from the web3 stuff that is done behind the scenes.

The problem is that the Chrome extension does not do anything when I try to use it. Does not throw any errors, nothing. Any ideas ?!

I have also added the `/* global chrome */` tag at the beginning of App.js

My form method as following:

```
GetInfo = (event) => {

event.preventDefault();
this.state.rouDomains.methods.GetDomainInfo(this.state.value).call(function(err, result){
if(!err) {
let ipfsHash = 'https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/' + result[4];
this.setState({ipfs: ipfsHash});
console.log('hash: ', ipfsHash);

if (ipfsHash === 'https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/n/a') {
this.setState({eroare: 'This domain is not registered yet!'});
} else if (ipfsHash === 'https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/Not Available') {
this.setState({eroare: 'This domain does not have any content yet!'});
} else {
chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: ipfsHash});
}
}
}.bind(this)
);
}
```

Please note the `chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: ipfsHash});`

For my background.js file, I am using:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
});
```

My manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "Myapp",
"description": "Visit myapp",
"author": "me",
"icons": {
"180": "img/logo192.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "0.1",
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "index.html",
"default_icon": "img/logo192.png"
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "webRequest", "<all_urls>"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-bB/HZ1RTIlJg4jeDw46QZxgS3onh2gJX1k0QObVJ4E4='; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Thank you so much,

Cristian

Comment: Please note that `extension.webRequest` is deprecated. I would look into updating your message passing to use `runtime.sendMessage`. Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage

Comment: FWIW There should be no need for messaging - why don't you just do `location.href = ipfsHash`?

Comment: @wOxxOm it is working with location.href in the react app, but not in the chrome browser, just tried... I am thinking that there are other settings for React that I am not aware about...

Comment: @jasonandmonte Do you have a practical example please?  Would really benefit and be great for learning purposes. Thanks

Comment: Ah, so this is a browser_action popup, in which case you can call chrome.tabs.update directly in your app, no need for messaging.